# Using OS 2.2 DevicePolicyManager SDK classes on Android whilst supporting OS 2.1 devices

Tags: android, reflection, sdk

I want to use some [DevicePolicyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html) methods in my app.  The DevicePolicyManager was introduced in OS 2.2, but my app must continue to run on OS 2.1 devices.

Here's pseudocode for what I want to do:

```
if (needSecurity)
{
  if (runningOS2.2orGreater) 
  {
    // Invoke the required security policy, e.g.
    setPasswordQuality(myComponentName, PASSWORD_QUALITY_NUMERIC)
  }
  else
  {
    // Tell the user they can't use this feature
  }
}
```

From reading the docs I think I may also need a [DeviceAdminReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html) to handle onPasswordFailed and onPasswordSucceeded callbacks.

From other Stackoverflow questions (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914371/is-there-a-way-to-use-features-in-android-2-1-2-2-while-keeping-a-minsdk-version/2914757#2914757)), I believe I have two options:

**1. Reflection**

Continue to build against OS 2.1 SDK and use reflection to invoke classes at runtime, e.g.

```
Class myClass =                                                                        
  ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager")

Object DPMInstance = myClass.newInstance();                                            

Method myMethod = myClass.getMethod("setPasswordQuality",                              
                                    new Class[] { ComponentName.class,                 
                                                  int.class });                        
myMethod.invoke(DPMInstance,                                                           
                new Object[] { myComponentName,                                        
                               PASSWORD_QUALITY_NUMERIC });
```

If I need to implement a DeviceAdminReceiver, will reflection work?  How would I handle callbacks to DeviceAdminReceiver and call back into my own application classes?

**2. Conditional class loading**

Change to build against the OS 2.2 SDK.  At runtime only load the OS 2.2 classes if the current device version is OS 2.2 or newer, e.g.

```
int sdk = new Integer(Build.VERSION.SDK).intValue();

if (sdk > 7) 
{
  sLog.info("OS 2.2 or later");
  return new myClassImplementsDeviceAdminInterfaces();
}
else
{
  sLog.info("OS 2.1 or earlier");
  return new myClassDoesNotSupportDeviceAdmin();
}
```

This approach looks like it will produce easier code to support, and presumably will work with a DeviceAdminReceiver too.  Is anybody aware of any drawbacks or complications to it?

So, my questions are:

- Would you recommend reflection or conditional class loading for using DevicePolicyManager?
- Will I need a DeviceAdminReceiver, or can I detect whether the user has a suitable password, e.g. by repeatedly calling [isActivePasswordSufficient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#isActivePasswordSufficient%28%29) in my app to confirm it has been done?
- Any other tips if you have them (e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475653/how-to-enforce-user-to-change-passwd-after-password-expiration-timeout-in-android) suggests there might be issues forcing the user to reset their password).

Thanks!

Comment: This is awesome, I did not even know these APIs existed on 2.1 but were simply hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I need to implement a DeviceAdminReceiver, will reflection work?

Not really. You'd need to use conditional class loading, which means you may as well just go that route to begin with.

> Is anybody aware of any drawbacks or complications to it?

Speaking on behalf of my little corner of "anybody", I'm not aware of any drawbacks. I'd use the `VERSION_CODES` constants on `Build`, though, rather than the integer (`7`). And, unless you're supporting 1.5, you can use `SDK_INT` on `Build` rather than `SDK`.

> Would you recommend reflection or conditional class loading for using DevicePolicyManager?

Conditional class loading.

> Will I need a DeviceAdminReceiver, or can I detect whether the user has a suitable password, e.g. by repeatedly calling isActivePasswordSufficient in my app to confirm it has been done?

That I can't answer. If you don't get another answer addressing this point, you might consider asking that in its own SO question.

> Any other tips if you have them

Never get involved in a land war in Asia.