# Is there an Android OS 2.1 API to find out if a device screen lock password is setup?

Tags: android, security, android-sdk-2.1

Is there a way to find out if the user has a device lock password setup on Android OS 2.1 (i.e. as set up through `Settings -> Location & security -> Change screen lock`)?

My application wants to check this minimum level of security is present before providing access to some of its content.

Here's where I have got to:

- [DevicePolicyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html) provides a
  way to set and inspect the device
  password policies, but that API only
  appears in OS 2.2.
- I know at least some OS 2.1 devices
  allow you to set a device password
  lock (i.e. you have to enter numbers
  or letters instead of just using a
  swipe lock).
- I've seen various [forum
  posts](http://androidforums.com/htc-hero-sprint/81740-2-1-now-enforces-exchange-policy-phone-lock.html) saying that OS 2.1 enforces
  Exchange e-mail policies (is this some
  sort of internal only implementation 
  of DevicePolicyManager?)
- The closest I have found is
  Settings.Secure
  [LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED). 
  Apparently that will only tell you if
  a pattern/swipe lock is set, [not
  whether a password is set](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/2be956312fc408ba) though.

I was hoping that there might be some OS 2.1 way to inspect if a password is present, rather than having to rely on a OS 2.2 API (which is [rather complicated to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811761/using-os-2-2-devicepolicymanager-sdk-classes-on-android-whilst-supporting-os-2-1) whilst still supporting OS 2.1 devices).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't force the user to set a Password for the whole device, but instead make something like a Password-Protection for your app (Like in 'Dropbox').

For this, I'd use a [EditText in 'Password mode'](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3apassword).

Comment: Thanks, but in my scenario we specifically want to do password protection across the whole device as: 1) It's annoying to a user to enter a device password and then an application password too, 2) My app includes a widget, which doesn't really fit the model of an in-app password, 3) This approach is consistent with many other Android apps, e.g. Facebook, e-mail etc.